# How to see that this map is not smooth?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y) = x^2$ and define $g(x,y) = {x \cdot f(x,y) \over x^2 + y^2 } = {x^3 \over x^2 + y^2}$.

In [this book here](https://books.google.com/books/about/Curves_and_Singularities.html?id=rhq3YCguBOUC&redir_esc=y) it is stated (on page 86) that this function does not extend to a smooth function in a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$.

But I don't see why $g$ should not be smooth on all of $x$. I took a derivative but that didn't yield any insight and then I plotted it for different min values of x,y ([here](http://www.livephysics.com/tools/mathematical-tools/online-3-d-function-grapher/?xmin=-1&xmax=1&ymin=-1&ymax=1&zmin=Auto&zmax=Auto&f=x%5E3%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29)) and it looks smooth:

[image]

> Please could someone explain to me why $g$ is not smooth on $\mathbb
>  R^2$?

Answer (score 1):

It is not smooth as it is at least not differentiable at $(0,0)$. Consider the directional derivatives at the origin in the directions $(1,\lambda)$.